# Using Moment.js with Twig

Tags: javascript, twig, momentjs

I am using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs) with Twig for calculating Time ago,

**Code (Twig)** -
I have date in `post_date_gmt` variable and i am using it like,

```
<div class="time">
  <time datetime="{{ post_date_gmt| date('Y-m-d H:i:s')}}">moment.unix({{ post_date_gmt }}).local().fromNow()</time>
</div>
```

This give me output :

```
<div class="time">
    moment.unix(1331845445).local().fromNow()  
</div>
```

When i try to run above string in console it worked fine - '*a month ago*'.
I don't understand why twig is not giving me the correct output?
Am i doing something wrong?. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moment is a javascript function and you're trying to call it from a block of HTML instead of a block of javascript. There are several ways you could do it, but an easy hack would be:

```
<div class="time">
  <time datetime="{{ post_date_gmt| date('Y-m-d H:i:s')}}">
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(moment.unix({{ post_date_gmt }}).local().fromNow());</script></time>
</div>
```

I don't recommend using document.write like that though. It would be better to do this as a separate block of javascript sort of like this (using jquery as an example):

```
<div class="time">
  <time id="time" datetime="{{ post_date_gmt| date('Y-m-d H:i:s')}}"></time>
</div>  

--- snip ---

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#time').val( moment.unix({{ post_date_gmt }}).local().fromNow() );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><p class="created"></p></li>                            
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $(".created").html(moment.unix({{ post_date_gmt| date('U') }}).local().fromNow());  
});
</script>
```